# Excel INDEX/MATCH not working for cells starting with "1/"

Tags: excel-formula

I'm using the INDEX/MATCH combination in a large number of rows in a worksheet tab to locate a cell value in another tab in the same worksheet and return the contents of another column in that second worksheet.

[INDEX/MATCH Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuxxJ.jpg)

Whilst this works fine for the majority of rows, I've discovered that a handful do not work - the cells show "#N/A".  Those that don't work are all looking for cells which begin with "1/" (ignore the quotation marks).

Can anyone help with why this would be the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you add 0 (0 after B:B) for exact match in your formula? It will then work.

Eg: `=INDEX(SAP!I:I,MATCH(Register!L2,SAP!B:B,0),0)`

Comment: Fantastic - that sorted it.  Thanks very much!